I need Advantage ODBC for Linux to connect Advantage Data Server
I need to find the Advantage ODBC for Linux for the SAP platform. For some time now from SAP downloads there is no way to download it.
Has anyone had it before and can pass it on to me? I have searched everywhere but without success.
Thanks,
I have searched everywhere on the internet but have not found any.
I have sent a ticket to SAP but their answers are always generic.
